# Using XmlSerializer and setting root class name

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, .net-4.5

Trying to work with XmlSerializer to nicely deserialize stuff I get from webservice.

Here is my class declaration:

```
[Serializable]
    public class CarrierLookupResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ResponseDO")]
        public ResponseDo ResponseDo { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is how XML looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CarrierService.CarrierLookup>
  <ResponseDO>
    <status>APPROVED</status>
    <action>OK</action>
    <code>SFW00389</code>
    <displayMsg></displayMsg>
    <techMsg></techMsg>
  </ResponseDO>
```

Here is code I use to deserialize:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarrierLookupResponse));
            var carrierLookupResponse = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(response.Key)) as CarrierLookupResponse;
```

Problem is simple. Service returns "CarrierService.CarrierLookup" and I need to force it to deserialize into "CarrierLookupResponse"

I can't put XmlElement attribute on class itself, so I have no idea how to map this name properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with XmlRoot attribute?

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("CarrierService.CarrierLookup")] 
    public class CarrierLookupResponse
    {
    ...
```